# ubuntu didn't restart after using testdisk

Tags: grub2, testdisk

I recently switched to ubuntu 14.04 from windows 8. I mistakenly choose remove windows 8 and install ubuntu. By doing this all my windows drive was wiped out. Then I searched for data recovery and found "TestDisk". I restored the main files I want then I press WRITE. Then after that I restarted the ubuntu. After I restart it shows me grub resue> screen and ubuntu didnt worked at all. Then I tried restoring/repairing the grub according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. It shows me the operation was successful but I get black screen while reboot. Below is the detail

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8333520/

Please help me on this. I do not want to lose any data recovered from testdisk. Also if possible can anybody give quick solution. I need ASAP help.

Answer (score 1):

When restoring, you may have confused Ubuntu where the install was due to the nature of hard drives. Try doing a fresh ubuntu reinstall after plugging the drive into another computer and copying the files you want off it.

PS: You cannot recover Windows OS from Testdisk. Whatever you could get off your lucky to have, but you can restore Windows with the recovery partition.

Comment: Since I didn't get any quick help, I copied the recovered files to external harddisk and am reinstalling the Ubuntu. Anyway thanks for taking time for answering.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Might want to edit your post as solved to prevent future mishaps! :D Well, I hope you got everything sorted out.